# aar doesn't include local dependecies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, aar

I have a group of library modules (A, B, C, D) which A is the main module that imports B, C and D.

A (build.gradle):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':B')
    implementation project(':C')
    implementation project(':D')
    ...
}
```

So, when I export and then import the `.aar` of main (A) module to other android project it doesn't recognise things of B, C and D modules in code. It is obvious that A dependencies are not present.

I read related posts about aar dependencies but solutions doesn't work for me. I am using **gradle 3.2.1**.

**UPDATE:**

Also I tried with `api` instead of `implementation`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    api project(':B')
    api project(':C')
    api project(':D')
    ...
}
```

But same result...

Comment: Use API instead of implementation

Comment: @Himeshgoswami I did that but got same result